Query to flag user: SQL2022 Update is needed
My software, compatible with all versions of SQL2016 and up including SQL Azure, crashes when SQL 2022 is lower than Version 16.0.1135.2 or lower than 16.0.4165.4 - depending on RTM, GDR, CU (which I'm having a hard time understanding the version architecture MS uses)
I wrote this code to find out if an SQL update is needed
-- if it's Version 16
IF (select substring(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')),1,charindex('.',convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))-1))='16'
-- If so is it 16.0.1xxxxxxx or 16.0.4xxxxxxxx
    IF (select substring(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')),1,charindex('16.0.',convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))))='1'
-- if 16.0.1 it needs to be < 16.0.1135.2 
BEGIN 
        if (select substring(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')),charindex('16.0.',convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))),len(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))))<'16.0.1135.2'
 select 1
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
-- if 16.0.4 it needs to be < 16.0.4165.4 
        IF (select substring(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')),1,charindex('16.0.',convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))))='4'
            if (select substring(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')),charindex('16.0.',convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))),len(convert(varchar(20),SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')))))<'16.0.4165.4'
            select 1 
END 

My problem is that in 16.0.YYYY.z, I don't think I can rely on the first Y to tell me what branch I should look at because looking at previous SQL versions, in the same branch the first Y can change digit...
What I'm looking for are the 2 versions updated before 2024-11-12
I want to be flagged if the SQL2022 version installed doesn't include the updates of 2024-11-12

Is there a standard I can follow or would there be a better way of doing this?
Should I worry about Azure or can I assume that Azure is always up to date?


We want to let the user know that they need a minimum of 16.0.1135.2 or 16.0.4165.4. My concern is selecting the branch (='1' or ='4') in the query. I don't think it will be reliable with time (the digit can change) as I'm not sure of the convention that MS uses.
The Software has over 30000 scripts (over 30 years of development) and thousands of customers. The upgrades are done by specialists (and not by the customer). Since it is updated four times a year, we want to add a warning during the upgrade if we find that the SQL server is incompatible so that the specialist can take action.


Is there a standard I can follow or would there be a better way of
doing this?

Not really as your issue is quite specific. As others have mentioned, the 'correct' way to handle would be to fix the application bug that causes the crash.

Should I worry about Azure or can I assume that Azure is always up to
date?

Azure SQL Database has diverged from the SQL Server codebase so the version numbers etc don't really correlate to SQL Server version numbers anymore. If you're not encountering the issue on Azure SQL then its probably safe to simply ignore it for now.

My problem is that in 16.0.YYYY.z, I don't think I can rely on the
first Y to tell me what branch I should look at because looking at
previous SQL versions, in the same branch the first Y can change digit

Convert them to INT values so you can so simple number comparisons instead rather than the complicated string manipulation. Use SERVERPROPERTY to pull the ProductBuild property and assess that:
DECLARE @MajorVersion INT
    , @ProductBuild INT

SELECT @MajorVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS INT)
    , @ProductBuild = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild') AS INT)

IF (@MajorVersion) = 16 AND CAST((SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) AS VARCHAR(255)) NOT LIKE '%Azure%'
BEGIN
    IF (@ProductBuild) >= 1000 AND (@ProductBuild) < 1135
        OR (@ProductBuild) >= 4003 AND (@ProductBuild) < 4165
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Unsafe version of SQL 2022'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Safe version of SQL 2022'
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Not SQL 2022'
END

This code converts the ProductMajorVersion property (the first part of the Version number) to an INT, then converts the Build Number to an INT. These are then compared against the known upper and lower bounds for SQL 2022 to determine if it is an unsafe version or not.
Since you know that versions from 1135 and up, and from 4165 and up are safe, you really only need to check if the target server has a version between 1000 and 1135, or between 4003 and 4165. Converting to integers means you don't have to check for various possible first digits, you can safely assume that if its above 1135 then its fine. Since the GDR path will never exceed the 4003 lower watermark for the CU path, there won't be any conflict.
The script also checks the "Edition" property and if its Azure it skips the check altogether.
NOTE: If you find other versions later on that are also crashing, you would need to amend the script to check for a ProductBuild value between the new upper and lower watermarks as well.

god why
This seems rather foolish, all in all.

My software ... crashes when SQL 2022 is lower than Version 16.0.1135.2 or lower than 16.0.4165.4

Why? What's special about those?

Does your software behave differently on those CUs, or even between different major versions (including cloud instances)?
Does your software behave differently between Standard and Enterprise Edition?
Does your software behave differently depending on database compatibility level?

Maybe your customers have patching policies that don't allow them to patch every month, or even every three months. Are you going to fight with security/infrastructure people about this so your software doesn't crash when it can't handle a version number?
They could have lower environments that cumulative updates need to be tested and validated on before updating. Maybe they tested a CU in a lower environment and found a regression and they can't roll it out to production and need to wait for another one.
This sort of thing is very nearly none of your business as a software developer. Dependencies like this just waste everyone's time.

With all due respect, I see it more like a Bug introduced in SQL2022 since our Software works with Azure, SQL2016 to SQL2019 without any issues.
Our software crashes due to a bad build that has been addressed and fixed by MS.

@JohnG yes but why do it at all?
